# How to write a web service method which automatically executed when deployed

Tags: java, web-services, wildfly

I create a web service at my wildfly server which has a method like below:

```
public ArrayList<CustomerRecord> QueryCustomer(String[] name,String[] keyword,String client) throws JCoException
{
//  String client="700";
    System.out.println("Query Start");
     ArrayList<CustomerRecord> codelist=new ArrayList<CustomerRecord>();
     CustomerRecord codeItem=new CustomerRecord();
     JCoDestination destination;
     MyDestinationDataProvider myProvider = MyDestinationDataProvider.getInstance();
     MyDestinationDataProvider myProviderN = MyDestinationDataProvider.getInstance();
     if (Environment.isDestinationDataProviderRegistered())
     {
         try {
             destination= JCoDestinationManager.getDestination("ABAP");
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
             
         }
         
     }
     else
     {
        Environment.registerDestinationDataProvider(myProvider);
        
        myProvider.addDestination("ABAP700", JCOtest.connectProperties700);
        myProvider.addDestination("ABAP300", JCOtest.connectProperties300);
        ...
```

It will first check whether a registered DestinationDataProvider exist, if yes then use it, if not then create one. I also wrote a JSP to access this method.
Now I want to seprate this registration process into another method and let it run automatically when deployed or server startup? So how to do that? Maybe create a jar for the registration method and deployed as modules?Any help?Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the registration part to the `@PostConstruct` method of an startup singleton EJB. It would get executed by the server when the app is loaded.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class StartupBean {

    @PostConstruct
    private void registration() {
        //...
    }
}
```